# List of Apple Watch Workouts and Metrics

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, activity.app

According to Apple, there are 12 different workouts:
[image]
The screenshot only shows 4. **What are all 12 workouts?**

Also, Apple says you can select up to 5 metrics.
**What are all the different metrics?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 12 workout types are:

- Cycling (Indoor & Outdoor)
- Run (Indoor & Outdoor)
- Walk (Indoor & Outdoor)
- Swim (Pool & Open Water)
- Elliptical
- Rower
- Stair-Stepper
- Other (these can be labeled as various activities like *Strength Training*, but the label is purely cosmetic—it has no incidence on calorie computations)

The various metrics are:

- Duration
- Current Pace & Speed
- Average Pace & Speed
- Distance
- Laps
- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Heart Rate

They are not all available for every workout type. For instance, **Pace** is available for **Run**/**Walk**, while **Cycling** may show your **Speed**.

**Swims** cannot display **Current Pace**, only **Average Pace**.

**Laps** are only available during **Pool Swims**, whereas stationary machine workouts (such as **Elliptical** and **Indoor Cycling**) cannot display **Distance**-related metrics (eg. **Speed**).

**Pace** and **Distance** calculations for **Indoor Walks**/**Runs** are dependent on how well you’ve [calibrated your WATCH](https://support.apple.com/HT204516), and require that you swing your arms throughout the workout. Holding onto the handlebars will cause WATCH to think you are not exercising.

**Duration**, **Active**/**Total Calories** and **Heart Rate** are available for all workout types.

**Calorie** computations are calibrated over time, as you wear and use your WATCH. They factor in both your heart rate and the weight you’ve recorded in the **Health** app.

Answer (score 0):

As of watchOS version 3.1, there are twelve workout types.

Each workout type has a default sequence of metrics that the watch displays when using the "multiple metric" workout view. One can edit this sequence, adding or removing metrics and rearranging their order. Note, though, that once you edit the metrics sequence for a workout type, there's no easy way to revert to the default sequence. In the interest of allowing safer customization, let's document the default sequences here, by workout type.

---

**Outdoor Walk**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Heart Rate
- Distance

**Outdoor Run**

- Duration
- Current Pace
- Heart Rate
- Distance

**Outdoor Cycle**

- Duration
- Current Speed
- Heart Rate
- Distance

**Indoor Walk**

- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Hear Rate
- Distance

**Indoor Run**

- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Hear Rate
- Distance

**Indoor Cycle**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Heart Rate

**Elliptical**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Heart Rate

**Rower**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Heart Rate

**Stair Stepper**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Heart Rate

**Pool Swim**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Laps
- Distance

**Open Water Swim**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Average Pace
- Distance

**Other**

- Duration
- Active Calories
- Total Calories
- Heart Rate