# Which metrics in the iOS Health app can be natively tracked by Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

This question comes from the perspective of someone who's not yet a Watch owner, but considering a purchase primarily for [quantified-self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantified_self)-style health nerdiness.

There are fields/screens for many, many different metrics in the iOS Health app:

- Some of these fields are populated automatically just through daily
  use of one's iPhone, eg. steps.
- Some of these clearly require manual data entry, eg. waist circumference.
- I understand some of these are tracked by Apple Watch, eg. cardio fitness, stand minutes.

I'm interested in this third category. **Is there a full list somewhere of all the metrics that the Watch can natively track?**

Comment: NB. similar-but-different question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257168/list-of-apple-watch-workouts-and-metrics